# how to avoid print null when value is not in th:text in Thymeleaf page

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

when value is not in th:text it is printing null on the page. how to handle this condition on thymeleaf page

This is Thymleaf code:

```
<tr th:each="respondentdata,status : ${complaintPdfBean.respondent}">
                 <td th:text="'Respondents No : ' + ${respondentdata.id}"></td>
                 <td>
                 <p th:text="${respondentdata.respondentDesignationname+','+respondentdata.respondentOffice+','+respondentdata.respondentothersOrg+','+respondentdata.respondentsubOrgName+','+respondentdata.respondentdepartmentName+','+respondentdata.citytownvillage}"></p>
                 
                 </td>
                </tr>
```

and this is the screenshot where value is not then it is showing null

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqfjK.png

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to achieve this. I would like to provide a couple of the simplest ones...

You may use Thymeleaf Expression Utility [#objects](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#objects) to check for null your object. Your code may look like the following:

```
<p th:text="${#objects.nullSafe(respondentdata.respondentDesignationname,'')+','+#objects.nullSafe(respondentdata.respondentOffice,'')+','+ .... so on .....}"></p>
```

You may use Thymeleaf Conditional Evaluation [th:if](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) attribute with Expression Utility [#strings](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings) object by dividing your paragraph `p` into small chanks of `span`. Your code may look like the following:

```
<p>
<span th:unless="${#strings.isEmpty(respondentdata.respondentDesignationname)}" th:text="th:text="${respondentdata.respondentDesignationname + ','}"></span>
<span th:unless="${#strings.isEmpty(respondentdata.respondentOffice)}" th:text="th:text="${respondentdata.respondentOffice + ','}"></span>
<span>.... so on ....</span>
</p>
```